# stop subprocess from initiating a process more than once

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a pythonic question:
lets say I am using the subprocess library in python to run a program from the terminal. I need to call the subprocess in a loop.
How can I:
1) I stop subprocess from initiating the program if it has already started. Or...
2) How can I find out if the program is still running so that I don't initiate a new subprocess?

Comment: Are you only concerned about instances of the sub-process being started by your Python script? Could you just wait for the subprocess to finish before moving on to the next iteration of the loop?

Comment: Sometimes I need to caught it before it stops. And some other times I want to wait till it finishes before repeating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the process is running using [`Process.poll`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll). It will return `None` if the process is currently running. Otherwise, it will return the exit code of the sub-process. For example:

```
import subprocess
import time

p = None
while True:
   if p and p.poll() is None:
       print("Process is currently running. Do nothing.")
   else:  # No process running
       if p:  # We've run the process at least once already, so get the result.
           ret = p.returncode
           print("Last run returned {}".format(ret))
       p = subprocess.Popen(["some_command", "some arg"])
   time.sleep(3)  # Wait a few seconds before iterating again.
```